# Random exception from telegram API

Tags: python, telegram

Okay so the following:
I have a simple bot that's running in this loop:

```
def teleupdater():
    try:
        updater.start_polling()
    except:
        pass
```

The problem is, sometimes (and I really mean sometimes, sometimes after 1 week, sometimes after 1 hour and I checked everything. It's not a certain event when the error occurs. It seems very random) I get this error:
https://pastebin.com/4iYB4Dqq
I honestly have no clue what this is and it also seems that it doesn't effect the bots performance in any way.

Comment: urllib3 supports requests with retries and backoffs. Is there a way to take advantage of that with telegram?

Comment: Sorry what? I don't fully understand.